# how to check installed apps android

Tags: android

hey can anyone explain to me this if condition , btw the code works but i dont understand the if condition

```
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
        if((app.flags & (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP | ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)) > 0) {
  

            // It is a system app
        } else {
            // It is installed by the user
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo) on what those flags means. With that, you can understand that condition.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of installed apps on Android, the code is used as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> appsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```